# Function clear is not a spy or a call to a spy

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, vitest, spy

I'm trying to test the navigation bar expecially the log out button but I keep getting this error

`[Function clear] is not a spy or a call to a spy!`

here is my test

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar";
import { vi, test, describe, expect } from "vitest";

describe("NavBar component", () => {
  test("render the navBar correctly", () => {
    const setTokenMock = vi.fn();
    render(<NavBar setToken={setTokenMock} />);
  });

  test("Log out if log out button is clicked", () => {
    const setTokenMock = vi.fn();

    const { getByText } = render(<NavBar setToken={setTokenMock} />);

    fireEvent.click(getByText("Déconnexion"));

    expect(setTokenMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith("");

    expect(localStorage.clear).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Can you tell  me what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you for you help

Comment: it might be happening because of localStorage.clear is not being recognized as a spy. In Jest, you need to mock localStorage.clear before you can assert whether it has been called or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't spying on `localStorage.clear`, so `vi` can't determine if it's been called or not.

```
const localStorageClearSpy = vi.spyOn(localStorage,'clear')

...

expect(localStorageClearSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```